# Adding elements to a webpage

Tags: javascript

I have this code that I've edited: http://pastebin.com/vrqHek6S
I've put in comments where I edited. Lines 75-75 & Lines 156-166

How would I get these edits from an external java-script file... I've tried for 3 hours to learn how to use "document.body.appendChild" "document.createElement" &  "divTag.innerHTML" and I've gotten no where.

Thanks,
Andrew Pearson

ps. This is my first post so if I did something wrong please tell me

Edit: this is what i've tired http://pastebin.com/ZaJJYsPq

```
   Potatoswatter you are correct
```

Edit: Sorry guys its late and my mind just isn't working how it should.  What I'm trying to do is create Div and fill the div with the Lines I listed, but I want to do this with pure js since I can't do any major edits on the html page (I can only add external js to the head.

Comment: There's no JavaScript in the indicated edits. "How would I get these edits from an external java-script file..." — do you want JavaScript code that would add the those HTML elements to the page?

Comment: Do you want us to give you the JavaScript code that will do this edit instead of you? If so, show what have you tried already.

Comment: > I'm Learning Javascript

Good for you

Comment: If you could try to show a simplified example of the problem (i.e. one that is less than 1000 lines of code) it'd be a lot easier on the eyes. Plus I'm not entirely sure what it is you are asking. What does "get these edits" mean?

Comment: @Andrew35133, pease make sure **small** samples of code that demonstrate your problem are present in the question. Rigth now there is no code in your question (links don't count).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little bit of JS you included, it looks like you're trying to create a `div` through pure JS, but your JS is wrong.

```
divTag.innerHTML = "<a class=\"sidetab\" href=\"#tab_dynmap\" id=\"tabhead_dynmap\"><img src=\"Images/DynMap.png\" alt=\"DynMap\" /><span>DynMap</span></a>";
```

**You need to escape your quotes.**

--

> How would I get these edits from an external java-script file.

I'd copy and paste...

> Lines 75-75 & Lines 156-166

These lines do not contain any JS:

```
 <a class="sidetab" href="#tab_dynmap" id="tabhead_dynmap"><img src="Images/DynMap.png" alt="DynMap" /><span>DynMap</span></a>

<div class="tabarea" id="tab_dynmap">
                        <h3>DynMap</h3>
                        <img src="Images/Map.png" alt="dynmap" class="tabimg"/>
                        <div class="tabcontents">
                            <div id="mapArea">
                                                <iframe src="http://mc.zephyrgaming.net/Dynmap/" height="500px" width="100%"> </iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Right I am trying to create a div from pure js.  

So my problem is I'm not allowed to mess with the html body just the head.  I need away to call a js to create the div i need :/  I'm just lost and its getting late so I'm mind is not working how it should.

Comment: For starters, your JS is invalid. Look at my comment, you need to escape your quotes.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what escape your quotes mean :/  I'm new at this, sorry

Comment: He means, since your markup string contains `"` `<a class="<-- this`, you need to escape it so that they are part of the string, and not interpreted as javascript code. You escape those using `backslash (\)`: `var string = "Alerting double quotes (\")"; alert(string);`

Comment: Ohhh, now I see his example and how he "escaped". So when I'm writing js and I need to write html or something with a " that doesn't need to be read as js i need to put a \ in front of the "?

Comment: Do I did what yall taught me, woo no more errors, just don't know where my js is writing the interhtml :/

Answer (score 2):

So you want to know how to insert elements into DOM. Here are the links to MDN:

- `.appendChild` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild
- `.createElement` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:document.createElement
- `.innerHTML` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.innerHTML

You can learn new things in MDN. It is a good reference site.